# Dataframe- reducing daily data to annual frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with daily stock data over a 10y history. Is there a simple way to convert this into annual change, so row's for 2010, 2011 ....2017 etc rather than daily? It would simply need to show the change on the year for each column.

Comment: No one can understand what you want without looking at your data and your expected output. Please take this into consideration before asking a question.

Comment: Also please make an effort to paste text instead of pictures. You're working with pandas already so it shouldn't be so hard to `print(df.head())` and paste the output here.

Answer (score 1):

If your date is formatted as `datetime` you can create new column `Year`:

```
df['Year'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
```

Now you can group your data by year, I'm assuming you need `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby('Year', as_index=False)[list_of_columns_you_need].sum()
```

Alternatively, if you need different operation on each column you can use `agg`:

```
df = df.groupby('Year', as_index=False).agg('column1': 'sum', 'column2': 'mean') #hope you get the idea
```